# Sort dictionary by another list or dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

I need **sort** my dictionary by another element who determine your order.

```
unsorted_dict = {'potato':'whatever1', 'tomato':'whatever2', 'sandwich':'whatever3'}
```

This sorting can come as a list or a dictionary, whichever is easier.

```
ordination = ['sandwich', 'potato', 'tomato']
```

Dictionary after sort:

```
sorted_dict = {'sandwich':'whatever3', 'potato':'whatever1', 'tomato':'whatever2'}
```

Comment: What version of Python are you on ? why not use an order Dictionary ?

Comment: default dictionaries are unsorted

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted. Do you mean you want to print out items in a sorted manner or iterate the keys/values in a sorted manner? As @MooingRawr says, a collections.OrderedDict keeps a record of when keys were added, allowing you to traverse them in the same order.

Comment: 3.7 Python will retain the order you insert into, so it is possible to "sort" a dictionary... hence the question what version of Python.

Comment: Python 2.7. The sorts I found are made by alphabetical order or similars, I need a custom sort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an `OrderedDict` like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_dict = OrderedDict([(el, unsorted_dict[el]) for el in ordination])
```

What it does is create a list of tuples (pairs) using the `ordination` as first element and the value in `unsorted_dict` as second, then the `OrderedDict` uses this list to create a dictionary ordered by insertion.

It has the same interface as a `dict` and introduces no external dependencies.

EDIT: In python 3.6+ an ordinary `dict` will preserve insertion ordering as well.

Comment: In Python 3.6+ you can use a regular dict.  You my wish to add both options.  And your list compression has typo.

Comment: @pylang Edited. Your comment has 2 typos. ;)

Comment: This solution seems to work for me. However Is there any variation that allows me for example to have the same **unsorted_dict** and a **ordination** with 'n' additional elements which are not used?

Comment: @LucasdeLima Do you mean filtering?

Comment: Yes I think. Same **unsorted_dict** however **ordination** with one more element.

Comment: Add an `if` to the list comprehension

Comment: Duly noted. touche.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to do it:

```
sorted_dict = dict()
sorted_list = list((i, unsorted_dict.get(i)) for i in ordination)
for i in sorted_list:
    sorted_dict.setdefault(i[0], i[1])
```

The results is:

```
{'sandwich': 'whatever3', 'potato': 'whatever1', 'tomato': 'whatever2'}
```

This, like the second answer, first createas a tuple of sorted pairs but doesn't rely on any outside libraries.

Comment: It works, but I'm afraid to mess up my code, since the value of the dictionary can be anything and a tuple I believe to be impossible.